# Problems with Image Tag in Picturebox

Tags: c#, tags, drag, drop

So, i try to learn how to Drag and Drop an Image from one PictureBox to another and that works well. But how can i drag and drop the Image TAG from pictureox1 to picturebox2?

i currently have 3 source images and 3 drop boxes.
the dropbox6 is locked with a countdown after a buttonclick (see button2)

(later i will lock all dropboxes)

[image]

after i hit this button a countdown starts and if the countdown is 0 (ZERO) only then i can drag one of the 3 images to this box.

however, i have given each of these 3 images in the souceboxes a TAG name.
how can i drop this tagname also to the dropbox?

here is what i have so far:
(the Label labeled "Counter" is actually Label4 in the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        

        private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            ((PictureBox)sender).DoDragDrop(((PictureBox)sender).Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox4.AllowDrop = true;
            pictureBox5.AllowDrop = true;
            pictureBox6.AllowDrop = true;
            pictureBox6.Enabled = false;


        }

        private void pictureBox4_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox4_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox4_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Image getPicture = (Bitmap) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pictureBox4.Image = getPicture;
        }



        private void pictureBox5_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox5_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox5_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Image getPicture = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pictureBox5.Image = getPicture;
        }



        private void pictureBox6_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Image getPicture = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pictureBox6.Image = getPicture;
         
            timer1.Enabled = false;
           
        }

        private void pictureBox6_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox6_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
               
            timer1.Stop();
            label4.Text = counter.ToString();
            if(counter == 0)
            {
            pictureBox6.Enabled = true;
            label4.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop(); 
                  
            }
           
        }

       

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }

                
        
        private void pictureBox6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show(pictureBox6.Tag.ToString());

        }

        private int counter = 3;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 3;
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
            timer1.Start();
            label4.Text = counter.ToString();
            if(label4.Text == "0")
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
            pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.shoreSite_d_1_l_x_x;
            button2.Visible=false;
        }
    }

    internal class bild1
    {
        private Bitmap shoreSite_d_1_l_x_x;

        public bild1(Bitmap shoreSite_d_1_l_x_x)
        {
            this.shoreSite_d_1_l_x_x = shoreSite_d_1_l_x_x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When an Image is loaded its Tag, if it even has one,  is not. But you can copy it to the Picturebox and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MouseDown` you are saying what you want to transmit in the `DoDragDrop` call. In your current case you are transmitting the **image** `((PictureBox)sender).Image` but you can chose to transmit the **tag** as well...

```
private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).DoDragDrop(((PictureBox)sender).Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    ((PictureBox)sender).DoDragDrop(((PictureBox)sender).Tag, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

...Then make sure to parse for each possible input type in `DragDrop`

```
private void pictureBox6_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var image = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap) as Bitmap;
    var tag = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
    if (image != null)
    {
        pictureBox4.Image = image;
    }
    if (tag != null)
    {
        pictureBox4.Tag = tag;
    }
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Beware, that you will need to update all the code that checks that the data is `Bitmap` before it arrives at `DragDrop` ie in `DragEnter` and write code that handles both `Bitmap` and `Text`, otherwise the Drag functionality will break.

Comment: well, i want to drag and drop the Image AND the TAG.
i need the name of the current image that is in the picturebox.
since i can not grab it from the Propperties.Recources i tought i need to send the TAG of the original image (from the sourcebox)

Comment: I believe you can call DoDragDrop multiple times per mouse click. Once for each Image and Tag

Comment: is it possible to read out the picturename from the properties.resources? maybe within a timer which then puts it onto a label? if so, then i wont need to send the ATG because i just need a identificator for the picture currently in the dropbox.

Comment: Brilliant!! It works now. Thank you so much!! I was starting to be desperate.....

Answer (score 0):

**AWESOME!!**

It works now. I will continue this Project.

Comment: Glad it works, you can accept and upvote my solution if it answers your question.

Comment: You should know that using answers like a reply is a stack overflow no-no. I would remove the answers with your posted code if I were you, as leaving them might get your question deleted by moderators

Comment: i am new here. i still need to figure out how this website works. but thanks. im very happy.